# How do I use Devise and ActiveAdmin for the same User model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, activeadmin

I have ActiveAdmin and Devise working with Users. I would like to use Devise to log in regular non-admin users with the same User model. How can I do this? (I want to have an `admin` flag in the User model for only admins.) I tried adding the 2nd line to routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
devise_for :users
```

But it gave an error when I tried to list the routes

```
>rake routes
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Invalid route name, already in use: 'new_user_session'
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

I've created an authorization adapter which just checks `user.admin == true` and that is working OK for ActiveAdmin. https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/13-authorization-adapter.md

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found this http://dan.doezema.com/2012/02/how-to-implement-a-single-user-model-with-rails-activeadmin-and-devise/

But I ended up doing this

> Devise 3.4.1
>   ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre1
>   Rails 4.2.1

`routes.rb`

```
  devise_for :admin_users, {class_name: 'User'}.merge(ActiveAdmin::Devise.config)
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :users
  resources :users
```

`application_controller.rb`

```
  def access_denied(exception)
    redirect_to root_path, alert: exception.message
  end
```

`config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdminAdapter
config.on_unauthorized_access = :access_denied
```

(And changing all methods from `_user` to `admin_user`.)

`app/models/active_admin_adapter.rb`

```
class ActiveAdminAdapter < ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter
  def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
    user.admin == true
  end
end
```

And

```
rails generate migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean
```

Comment: Awesome answer.. Really very help full.

Comment: Thanks a ton, just logged in to upvote :) And thanks for the links too.

Comment: This does not solve the issue if you have different tables for admin_users and users. Devise will not let you login into admin without logging into users.

Comment: Some explanation on what the code above does would help me to configure ActiveAdmin my way.