# How to seperate two devise logins from user and admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin

I have a User model which i have used devise for authentication and then i installed active admin gem. It creates another login. My problem is that when i try to go into localhost:3000/admin it first redirects me to the first devise i created for the User model(users/sign_in) after i give a valid email and password then it will redirect me to the active admin login . I have used the default AdminUser model with active admin.

I am new so don't know how to configure the routes.

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
      devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
      ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
      devise_for :users
      get 'activities/index'
      get 'projects/index'
      get 'activities/new'
      resources :activities
      # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
      root 'dashboard#index'
    end
```

First i need to stop redirecting to users/sign_in on page load. If i give localhost:3000/admin in browser path and don't redirect to user dashboard when logged in as admin.Thanks.

Comment: do you have any custom controllers related to devise? (like sessions_controller.rb) If so, please post them as well

Comment: also seems like this question might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30249740/how-do-i-use-devise-and-activeadmin-for-the-same-user-model

Comment: @beniutek no i don't have any other custom controller i have a users_controller but there is no code in it.

Comment: @beniutek that question seems to be helpful. Thanks i will get back to you after trying this tomorrow.

Comment: @beniutek I want to implement roles in it can you suggest a way on how to achieve that ? i want hr,admin,manager to go to the admin panel.

Comment: My first guess would be to use can can gem, check out this link on the devise wiki on how to approach this problem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Integrate-with-CanCan-for-roles-management